# How do I change the Magit section heading background color?

Tags: magit, faces, customize

I'm trying to customize the look and feel of my Magit setup. How do I change the background color of the section heading below?

In particular, I'd like to change the black background color next to the "Unstaged changes" text.

(Normally I could do a `C-u C-x =` to get the face, but in this case I cannot click on this section heading)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Unstaged changes` line is not a section heading. Sections and their headings are part of the buffer text, but this line is not part of that, otherwise it would not stay in place when you scroll the buffer.

Instead this text is being displayed in the `header-line`. The face that controls the `Unstaged changes` part is `magit-header-line. The rest of the line is styled using the`header-line` face.

Comment: Thank you! That worked. Out of curiosity, how did you know it was the `magit-header-line` or `header-line` face that needed to be changed?

Answer (score 0):

For my solarized theme I have the following line in my `.emacs`.

```
(require 'magit)
(set-face-attribute 'magit-header-line nil :background "#073642")
```